# Ca-certificates won't allow complete RP Update

Tags: pi-3, apt

I'm trying to install 'Syncthing' on Raspberry Pi, which I have done several times in the past, the install requires that I run apt-get update.  This is using Rpi OS "stretch".

The update fails on a couple of lines that feature Syncthing:

```
Err:8 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing/stable armhf Packages

server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Failed to fetch https://apt.syncthing.net/dists/syncthing/stable/binary-armhf/Packages server certificate verification failed.
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Syncthing have advised that:

> your CA File is outdated and doesn’t include the Let’s Encrypt CA Cert, but only the third-party one, which has been invalid for some weeks

They advised that I try:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Neither of these suggestions have helped solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome.  You should clarify whether you are using the latest version of the OS (buster) or a previous one.

Comment: Has the clock properly synchronized? If the Pi couldn't update its system clock (from the internet), updating may fail due to no longer/not yet valid certificates.

Comment: So if typing 'date' gives the actual time on my system....then the time and date are correct.  Thanks for your help BTW

Answer (score 1):

`syncthing` is available in the Pi OS repositories. Unless you want a specific version, or the latest version which hasn't made it into Debian yet, you should remove all references to `https://apt.syncthing.net` from your apt sources and run `apt-get update` / `apt-get upgrade`. Check if `syncthing` is upgraded, if not, reinstall it.

If you need a specific version, it might be easier to install it from sources.

If you want to debug your certificate issue, check if you have the "ISRG Root X1" or "DST Root CA X3" certificate installed. Here's the complete chain:

```
    Common name: apt.syncthing.net
SANs: apt.syncthing.net
Valid from October 1, 2021 to December 30, 2021
Serial Number: 047e749a99fb953e42268a36876bfa6c8589
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: R3  
     
    Common name: R3
Organization: Let's Encrypt
Location: US
Valid from September 3, 2020 to September 15, 2025
Serial Number: 912b084acf0c18a753f6d62e25a75f5a
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: ISRG Root X1    
     
    Common name: ISRG Root X1
Organization: Internet Security Research Group
Location: US
Valid from January 20, 2021 to September 30, 2024
Serial Number: 4001772137d4e942b8ee76aa3c640ab7
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: DST Root CA X3
```